# invariant Subspace M for T

Tags: functional-analysis

given an example of an Invariant operator T on a Banach space X and an invariant Subspace M for T such that M is not invariant for $T^{-1}$.

T is invariant if $x\in T(M)$    then $x \in M$.

Comment: What is an invariant operator?

Comment: my try : if M be finite dimension then it false. so M has infinity dimension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X=\ell^{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ (Thus, elements of $X$ are sequences indexed by $Z$: $(...,a_{-2},a_{-1},\widehat{a_0},a_1,a_2,...)$, where $\widehat{\cdot}$ denotes the $0$-position). Take the right shift $S:V\to V$ such that $V(...,a_{-2},a_{-1},\widehat{a_0},a_1,a_2,...)=(...,a_{-3},a_{-2},\widehat{a_{-1}},a_0,a_1,...)$. Analogously take $T:V\to V$ as the left shift.

Clearly $S^{-1}=T$.

If $U=\{(...,a_{-2},a_{-1},\widehat{a_0},a_1,a_2,...)\in V:a_{-i}=0\,\,\forall i>0\}$, then $U$ is a subspace of $V$ and $S(U)\subseteq U$.

But $(...,0,0,\widehat{1},0,0,...)\in U$ and $T(...,0,0,\widehat{1},0,0,...)=(...,0,1,\widehat{0},0,0,...)\notin U$. Then $U$ isn't $T=S^{-1}$-invariant.